# Getting a Cloud Firestore document reference from a documentSnapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

## The issue

I'm trying to retrieve the document reference from a query.  My code returns `undefined`.  I can get the path by extracting various parts of `documentSnapshot.ref`, but this isn't straightforward.

What I'd like to return is a reference which I can then later use to `.update` the document, without having to specify the collection and use `documentSnapshot.id`

The documentation for the `path` property is [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.11.x/DocumentReference#path)

## My code

```
const db = admin.firestore();

return db.collection('myCollection').get().then(querySnapshot => {
  querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
    console.log(`documentReference.id   = ${documentSnapshot.id}`);
    console.log(`documentReference.path = ${documentSnapshot.path}`);
    // console.log(`documentReference.ref = ${JSON.stringify(documentSnapshot.ref)}`);
  });
});
```

## Output

```
documentReference.id   = Jez7R1GAHiR9nbjS3CQ6
documentReference.path = undefined
documentReference.id   = skMmxxUIFXPyVa7Ic7Yp
documentReference.path = undefined
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In your code, `documentSnapshot` is an object of type [DocumentSnapshot](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.11.x/DocumentSnapshot).  It looks like you're assuming that it's an object of type [DocumentReference](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.11.x/DocumentReference).  A the purpose of a reference is to locate a document.  The purpose of a snapshot is to receive the contents of a document after it's been queried - they're definitely not the same thing.  A DocumentSnapshot doesn't have a `path` property.

If you want the DocumentReference of a document that was fetched in a DocumentSnapshot, you can use the [ref](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.11.x/DocumentSnapshot#ref) in the snapshot. Then you can get a hold of the ref's path property:

```
documentSnapshot.ref.path
```

Comment: Hey Doug.  Thanks for that.  I looked at both the DocumentSnapshot and DocumentReference documentation and clearly had a moment of ignorance.  It's all working now.  I've used documentSnapshot.ref.path before, but couldn't find where I'd used it.

Comment: In python, it's `reference` instead of `ref`.

Comment: I couldn't find this in the docs.  So I don't need to use the data() method, I can just use .ref?